# Modifying bigInteger after dividing Java

Tags: java, biginteger

I've looked a lot through here and can't quite find why this line is wrong:

```
ArrayList <BigInteger> data = new ArrayList();
int [] primes = new int[25];    
...
// Some initializing
...
data.get(i) = data.get(i).divide( BigInteger.valueOf( primes[place] ) ); //<----
...
// Rest of the code
```

Required: variable;
Found: value.. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should fix your [Raw Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) (and I'd prefer the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface) like

```
List<BigInteger> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

then you need to use `set` because you can't assign to the return value of a `get` like that.

```
data.set(i, data.get(i).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(primes[place])));
```

Also, it's worth noting that [`BigInteger`(s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) are (per the Javadoc) *immutable arbitrary-precision integers*.

Answer (score 5):

`=` only works to assign variables, fields and array elements.

You probably want to call `set`.

```
data.set(i, data.get(i).divide(...etc...));
```